# How to get the content of a file sent via POST in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a form that sends a text file via POST method in Laravel 4. Inside the Controller, however, I can't figure out how to get its content in order to put it into a BLOB field in the DB.

Laravel's documentation and all the posts I found into the web, always show how to save the content into a file with the `->move()` method.

This is my code in the Controller:

```
$book = Books::find($id);
$file = Input::file('summary'); // get the file user sent via POST
$book->SummaryText = $file->getContent(); <---- this is the method I am searching for...
$book->save(); // save the summary text into the DB
```

(SummaryText is a MEDIUMTEXT on my DB table).

So, how to get the file content in Laravel 4.1, without having to save it into a file? Is that possible?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you're posting a text file to than it should already be on the server.  As per the laravel documentation, `Input::file` returns an object that extends the php class `SplFileInfo` so this should work:

```
$book->SummaryText = file_get_contents($file->getRealPath());
```

I'm not sure if the php method `file_get_contents` will work in the Laravel framework...if it doesn't try this:

```
$book->SummaryText = File::get($file->getRealPath());
```

Comment: Yes, `file_get_contents()` works under Laravel. I chose your first solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 16):

Since Laravel v5.6.30 you can get the file content of an uploaded file like:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::post('/upload', function (Request $request) {
    $content = $request->file('photo')->get();
});
```

source: [this commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/fd03dd44b9f41158fb55ceac8fe865de33366e65)

Comment: Thank you, +1 for pointing out the source code, which was a great help.

Answer (score 6):

Nicer solution instead of file_get_contents will be to use the SPL class methods as FileUpload is already extending them.

```
$file = Input::file('summary')->openFile();
$book->SummaryText = $file->fread($file->getSize());
```

To read more about SplFileInfo and SplFileObject see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php

As those could be really usefull and using SPL which is OOP is nicer solution than structural PHP functions.

Comment: What is nicer about it? Does it provide some inherit error checking?

Answer (score -1):

```
\File::get($directory.$filename);
```

Worked for my project, where directory and filename are determined by the upload methods.
The backslash is used when creating workspaces (packages) in laravel4.